# Reading excel using Open XML SDK c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, openxml-sdk

I am trying to read excel using Open XML SDK in C# using Visual Studio 2013. 
I followed the following links
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh298534(v=office.15).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx

The code is

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(excelPath, true))
{
  WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
  foreach (WorksheetPart workSheetPart in workbookPart.WorksheetParts)
  {
   SheetData sheetData = workSheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
   IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(x => x.RowIndex > 1);
   foreach (Row r in rows)
    {
     IEnumerable<string> textValues = from cell in r.Descendants<Cell>() where cell.CellValue != null select cell.CellValue.Text;
     foreach (var cell in textValues)
     {
     string str = cell.ToString();
     }
    }
   }
 }
```

I tried the following code also

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(excelPath, true))
{
 WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
 foreach (WorksheetPart workSheetPart in workbookPart.WorksheetParts)
  {
   SheetData sheetData = workSheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
   IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(x => x.RowIndex > 1);
   foreach (Row r in rows)
   {
    List<Cell> cells = r.Descendants<Cell>().ToList();
    foreach (var cell in cells)
    {
     if (cell != null)
     {
     string value = cell.CellValue.Text;
     if (cell.DataType != null)
     {
     switch (cell.DataType.Value)
      {
      case CellValues.SharedString:
        var stringTable = workSheetPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (stringTable != null)
        {
         value = stringTable.SharedStringTable.ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
         }
         break;
       }
      }
   }
}                  
}
}
}
```

But both are returning only numeric values, not text. Can anyone please help on how to read excel text using Open XML SDK in C#.?

Comment: please show your relevant code

Comment: OpenXML uses a Shared String table, which means instead of text you get an index referring to the value in the table.  I'm not at a machine where I can test this, but I suspect that'll be the problem.

Comment: I have tried getting values from Shared String table also. Added that code to question. But it is also not working. It returns only numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used to OpenXML SDK directly, but have you tried used [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com)? It's a wrapper around the SDK that makes reading and writing Excel documents a breeze.